# Winform Designer Application

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, visual-studio

Friends, I need a application for designing forms - in the style of visual studio/winform designer. Does anyone know any project I can use to study or adapt? At the end I need to develop a tool in C# that generates an XML containing all the formatting and screen elements.

Any help or recommendation is welcome.
Thank you.

Comment: Something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5486009/custom-form-designer-by-using-visual-c-sharp-net)?

Comment: You can't use Visual Studio because...?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163634.aspx

Comment: @Greg I need to modify the generated script. The number of components is very limited.

Comment: @Ph.E - You are most welcome.  BTW, you have an answer below, please accept it if it fits your needs!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You have the [SharpDevelop Winforms Designer](http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sd/) that can probably be adjusted to fit your needs.
- ...or perhaps the [MonoDevelop Winforms Designer](http://www.mono-project.com/WinForms_Designer)
- If that is not enough, have a look at this [CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24385/Have-a-Great-DesignTime-Experience-with-a-Powerful) describing how to use a [Microsoft Design Surface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.design.designsurface.aspx) to implement a customer forms designer.

If you still need more detailed control, [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/magazine/cc163871.aspx) describes how to create your own .NET Forms Designer, more or less from scratch. It comes with [source code and a pre-built executable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/magazine/cc164730.aspx).

In the end the solution depends on the details of your problem and the kind of user-support you need to provide.